# How to do same process to perform same oprenation i do forground angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe in background using angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I have a messaging service ts file where I have subscribed to angularFireMessaging.messages, and do set operation's where I set ngrx store data and update data too. Thing is this only works in foreground

How to perform the same for background too? Any ideas are welcoming.\

I am using firebase-messaging-sw.js as service worker and import {AngularFireMessaging} from '@angular/fire/messaging'; in messaging service. import {AngularFireMessaging} from '@angular/fire/messaging';

```
import {AngularFireMessaging} from '@angular/fire/messaging';
constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
   this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => {});
}
```

Comment: Can you define "foreground" and "background"?

Comment: @Fredrik_Macrobond
the foreground is when that website tab active and your active window is also that,
If go out that window or tab which is opening another website, then your app starts to run in the background

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. And I'm sorry, but I cannot help you in this case.